# How to access the nested resource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TopKey" TargetType="local:CustomType">
        <Style.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="NestedKey">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then I have the following declaration:

```
<local:CustomType ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TopKey.NestedKey}"/>
```

Of course the above line doesn't compile and I don't know how to resolve this...

Comment: Why can not directly access to the `NestedKey` - `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NestedKey}"`?

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev: In my source it doesn't compile neither.

Comment: Why not flatten the nesting ?

Comment: Try to separate `Style` and `DataTemplate`. Typically, they are stored separately, as they are different in type and purpose. Most likely, the design like yours, will not work. In `Style.Resources` properties should be relevant only to the `Style`, not the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a Resource in a ResourceDictionary of a FrameworkElement means that you don't want the Resource to be accessible outside this FrameworkElement (though you could get around it in code behind).

In your case NestedKey is in the wrong ResourceDictionary. Try something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NestedKey">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="TopKey" TargetType="local:CustomType">
        <!-- here I can use {StaticResource NestedKey} -->
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- in the same window I can use: -->
<local:CustomType ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NestedKey}"/>
```

You *could* also define a new Style that is based on the TopKey Resource, thus gaining access to it's ResourceDictionary (but that is a workaround to something you can do better)

```
<local:CustomType>
    <local:CustomType.Style>
        <Style BasedOn={StaticResource TopKey} TargetType="local:CustomType">
            <!-- here I can use {StaticResource NestedKey} -->
        </Style>
    </local:CustomType.Style>
</local:CustomType>
```

Comment: Useful hint with that accessibility. I thought about it more like namespaces.

Comment: @yBee I just thought of another way of handling your case (see edit). I guess in some cases this kind of grouping the resources in StyleResources might be usefull - when you want to reuse some specific resources in the whole app, but don't want to 'polute' the general ResourceDictionary. But generally it's best to stick with the first solution.

Answer (score 2):

simply do this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NestedKey">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="TopKey" TargetType="local:CustomType">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NestedKey}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<local:CustomType Style="{StaticResource TopKey}" />
```

hope that helps